# Memory full without any heavy apps

Tags: internal-storage

[image]

I dont have any heavy apps on my phone, but still a major part of memory of my k3note is occupied with 'others'.

Comment: See **Others**. I think you have lots of unsupported data in the internal memory.

Comment: All parts of the chart are tapable, just dig into the Others and check what is it consists of.

Answer (score 0):

`Others` contains all files that will not come under the app/pic/doc/zip/audio and video.

It occupies 7.* gb.

So, either click on `other` or go to file manager and check your custom folders for such heavy data files.